# Combination of N variables in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combinations, permutation

Here I Have some complex combination problem for VBA in Excel.
I have n variable defined by starting value, stop value and steps.
N variables are double values basically like below.

```
      Var1, Var2,  Var3, .... VarN
start:  20,    1,   0.1, ....  
stop : 100,   10,   1.0, ....
step :  10,    1,   0.1, ....
```

What is the most efficient (fast) way of generating combination of each variable like below:

```
20, 1, 0.1
20, 1, 0.2
20, 1, 0.3
...
...
...

100, 10, 0.8
100, 10, 0.9
100, 10, 1.0
```

I believe that there are all 900 combinations (=9x10x10) for this case.

More challenging part is that I need more flexible solution for N variable cases using double array like this (without involving any worksheet formula):

```
Private startValue() As Double ' start value of each variable
Private stopValue() As Double  ' stop value of each variable
Private stepValue() As Double  ' step value of each variable
Private combination() as double 'combination of all N variable
Private n as integer ' number of variable = N


ReDim startValue(1 To 1, 1 To n) As Double
ReDim stopValue(1 To 1, 1 To n) As Double
ReDim stepValue(1 To 1, 1 To n) As Double
```

I really appreciated for your kind help.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

Why you require 2 dimensional array if you want 3 arrays for startValue, stopValue and stepValue. Alternately, You can use only one 2-dimensional array

```
ReDim arrValue(0 To 2, 0 To n-1) As Double
```

where index 0 = Start, 1 = Stop, 2 = Step

Comment: Thanks. Can the N variable case be done efficiently in vba?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating an array and then assigning values to it, you can let `Excel` do the job by assigning a range to your variable (i.e. `arrMyValues = Range("A2:C4")`). But as in your case we don't know the last column, we first have to get the last column. We can get this by:

```
oWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

This will return the number of columns used in your sheet. In this instance however, we need the name of the last column. To get that we first get the last column addres:

```
oWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address
```

We then split this address into an array so that we can get the column name:

```
arrColAddress = Split(oWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address, "$")
```

Now that we have the name of the last column, we can use the name with row count to pass the range into our variable. To get the row count for the sheet, we can use:

```
oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

If we put all of this together (only thing I added was a worksheet object), we get:

```
Dim oWS as Worksheet : Set oWS = Worksheets("your worksheet name")
arrColAddress = Split(oWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address, "$")
arrMyValues = oWS.Range("A2:" & arrColAddress(1) & oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
```

Code is based on the table you provided

Comment: `arrColAddress = Split(oWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address, "$")' will give you the address for the last column in your sheet, which is then `Split` into an array. Next line `arrMyValues = oWS.Range("A2:" & arrColAddress(1) & oWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)': to explain: if you assign a `Range` to a variable, Excel will create the array for you. This line gives the range to be assigned in your array. Your question about the N variable I presumed you are looking for the last column used in the sheet. You can get this by: `Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: I've added explanation for the code. Hope this helps

Comment: Hi. Zac. Thanks for your code. Is this code can generate 900 combination of 3 variables like in my example. Further more, can this approach adapted for N variable case ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: All the code does is put the range from your sheet into a multidimensional array. by N variables do you mean N number of columns in the sheet? if so then yes the code will do that. Also not sure how you are arranging in combination of 3. So if you have 5 columns, how would you generate the 3 number combination?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which should work for any number of variables:

```
'The following takes a 1-based variant area with 3 rows
'And n columns, where n is the number of variables
'The first row are start values, the second is stop, and the
'third is step-size.
'It returns a variant array consisting of all combos

Function MakeCombos(Vals As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim numCombos As Long
    Dim combos As Variant, levels As Variant
    Dim var As Double, varStep As Double, colStep As Long

    If TypeName(Vals) = "Range" Then Vals = Vals.Value 'make into a VBA array if passed a range
    n = UBound(Vals, 2)
    ReDim levels(1 To n)

    'first find the *number* of levels for each variable
    numCombos = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        levels(i) = 1 + Round((Vals(2, i) - Vals(1, i)) / Vals(3, i))
        numCombos = numCombos * levels(i)
    Next i

    ReDim combos(1 To numCombos, 1 To n)

    'Now -- just fill in column by column in reverse order with some modular arithmetic
    colStep = 1 'how often value is changed in column
    For j = n To 1 Step -1
        var = Vals(1, j)
        varStep = Vals(3, j)
        combos(1, j) = var
        For i = 1 To numCombos - 1
            combos(i + 1, j) = var + (Int(i / colStep) Mod levels(j)) * varStep
        Next i
        'before next pass theough outer loop, increase colStep so that
        'in the next column will step more slowly
        colStep = colStep * levels(j)
    Next j

    MakeCombos = combos

End Function
```

To test it, I started with a spreadsheet that looks like:

[image]

Then ran this code:

```
Sub test()
    Range("F1:H900").Value = MakeCombos(Range("B2:D4"))
End Sub
```

After which the data in columns F:H starts with:

[image]

and 900 rows down ends with:

[image]

Comment: This is magic. John. Thanks so much. It is accurate and flexible. Great solution.

Comment: @auto9817 Glad I could help. If the answer solves your problems you could mark it as "accepted".

Comment: Where is accepted button located ? I can't see them in my web browser. Sorry for very naïve question. :)

Comment: @auto9817 The Stack Overflow interface is on the cluttered side (since there is so much going on). Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer